# RAD SERVER 10.4.1 " E2597(SystemPath)\ld-linux.exe: error: cannot find -lz " deploying to Linux 64

Tags: linux, rest, delphi, rad-studio

I am trying to re-compiling some API  in the 10.4.1 for Ubutun 18.04.4 LTS ( builded in RAD SERVER 10.3), but ever API who has this lib  "REST.Response.Adapter" the compiler fails and i get this error :

> [DCC Error] E2597 C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin\ld-linux.exe: error: cannot find -lz
> [DCC Fatal Error] F2588 Linker error code: 1 ($00000001).

I already installed some linux patch for 10.4.
I tried to reinstall the linux SDK, nothing....

Someone know anything about it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you need to install zlib1g-dev in your Linux system by the following command in a terminal.

`sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`

To ensure you have installed all the required libraries, you can also use this command:

`sudo apt-get install joe wget p7zip-full curl build-essential zlib1g-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev`

Secondly, reboot the Linux system and/or restart at least the PAServer.

Afterward, go to your SDK manager in the Delphi IDE within Linux 64-Bit and press the button *Update Local File Cache* below the remote path list under *Properties*.

BTW: If you had followed these instructions http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Linux_Application_Development properly in all points, this would not have happened to you ;).

Comment: I install all the libs and work!. Thank for your answer. Sorry about the delay of the response, i was on vaction. (and especial thanks for FB4D )

Comment: Hi, I have the same error on CENTOS, what lib I must to install on centos 8?

Comment: @Pedro: See https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-install-zlib-devel

Comment: unable to locate package zlibig-dev